# mysql select 5 random questions in each category

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following data in a table:

```
date_added category
15/10/2009 Novels
12/10/2009 Novels
12/10/2009 Novels
11/10/2009 Novels
17/10/2009 Films
16/10/2009 Films
15/10/2009 Films
15/10/2009 Films
etc.
```

I want a SQL(Mysql) query to return just the first (say) 2 rows in each Category, i.e.

```
15/10/2009 Novels
12/10/2009 Novels
17/10/2009 Films
16/10/2009 Films
```

Comment: Add sample table data and a possible expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @Hadi Nur,Post your image sample in same page.

Comment: @Mansoor, new users aren't allowed to include images.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky in MySQL.  I would recommend using variables:

```
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = category_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := category_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from questions q cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @c := -1) params
      order by category_id rand()
     ) q
where rn <= 5;
```

The subquery enumerates the questions for each category randomly.  The outer query then chooses the first five for each category.

Comment: thanks for the answe, but the code didnt work, I just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

*(I am not very good at mysql. I have given it a go.)*

**uuid()** function will generate Universal Unique Identifier each time.

**ORDER BY RandomID** will do the trick for random selection because every time you run the query RandomID will be uqique. Therefore, order by RandomID ASC or DESC each will order the record completely random.

**LIMIT** will show only 5 records.

**Final code:**

```
SELECT q.question_id, q.Question, c.category_id, uuid() AS RandomID
FROM Question q
INNER JOIN Category c
    ON q.Category_id=c.Category_id
ORDER BY RandomID ASC 
LIMIT 5
;
```

Comment: thanks for the answe, but the code didnt work, I just updated the question